# When Is Adventure Time set?

Tags: comics, cartoon, adventure-time

In several episodes I've seen, as well in the recent comic, we see glimpses of out present in fossil, disused subway tunnels (both in the recent comic) or as frozen business men:

[image: The Business men]

So does this mean that Adventure time is set in the future? Previously I thought the land of Ooo was in the past.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It turns out (after investigation) that Adventure time is in fact set some time in the future (postulated as ~1000 years). It is set after the *[Mushroom War](http://adventuretime.wikia.com/wiki/Mushroom_War)* and various relics can be seen through out the series indicating this. There is even a scene from *Ocean of Fear* with an old, dead couple sat in a pre-war house:

[image: Dead people]

In fact Pendleton Ward has [stated](https://www.facebook.com/video/video.php?v=1323244554426&ref=mf) that the *Land of Ooo* is post-apocalyptic.

Comment: +1 for catching a screen shot of the old couple! :)